# Access 2007 crashes when canceling On No Data and calling function from On Close

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

MS Access 2007 (and perhaps later versions) appears to have a bug that causes a hard crash when a report open is canceled in the On No Data event and the On Close event contains a call to a public function.  This does not appear to be an issue with MS Access 2003 or earlier.

### Steps to reproduce:

- Create a new report in MS Access 2007 (this is not an issue in MS Access 2003 and prior)
- Set the recordsource (it can be anything, but it must be a bound report)
- Set event On No Data to `[Event Procedure]`
- In the code module for the report, enter:

---

```
Private Sub Report_NoData(Cancel As Integer)`  
    Cancel = True
End Sub
```

- Set event On Close to `=Foo()`
- In a standard code module, add the following code:

---

```
Public Function Foo()
End Function
```

- Open the report using a filter that excludes all data (in order to raise the No Data event)

### Results:

- Access immediately suffers a hard crash with the "Access has stopped working..." error message

---

**Two questions:**

1. Is there a workaround?
2. Is this a known issue? (known to Microsoft or the greater MS Access community)

Answer (score 0):

**Workaround**

There are a couple of workarounds:

- Replace the function call in the report's On Close property with "[Event Procedure]" and then call the function from within the report's `Private Sub Report_Close()` in VBA.

  - OR -
- Move the function call from the report's On Close property to its On Unload property.  (*Note: the [On Unload report property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb257725(v=office.12).aspx) was introduced with MS Access 2007*)